# Accessing TemporaryFilePath in form_valid Django

Tags: django, django-views

Currently my users are able to upload files, as I am deployed via Heroku I am using Django-storages to upload to AWS S3 buckets. I am using a CreateView/UpdateView as below, this works well however I now want to be able to run an operation on the file before uploading to AWS, my research insofar suggests that I can use temporary_file_path() to do this in the form_valid however I am getting an error,
UpdateView/CreateView

```
class project_update(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm
    template_name = "home/update_project.html"
    context_object_name = 'project'
    success_url = reverse_lazy("project-list")
    def form_valid(self, form):
        handle_uploaded_boq(form['boq_file'].temporary_file_path(), form.cleaned_data['project_title'])
        return super(project_update, self).form_valid(form)
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
'BoundField' object has no attribute 'temporary_file_path'
```

So what is the best way to run the operation `handle_uploaded_boq()` before the file is uploaded to AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access the file in form_valid method you can use

```
form.files['boq_file']
```

and to access the path of uploaded file of [TemporaryUploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.TemporaryUploadedFile) class, use

```
form.files['boq_file'].temporary_file_path()
```

or

```
form.files['boq_file'].file.name
```

Note: to get the path of the uploaded file, the uploaded file must be an object of class TemporaryUploadedFile and not of InMemoryUploadedFile. You can handle it by updating the FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS in setting.py to following

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]
```

assuming that the name of file_field you used in the form is boq_file

Comment: I get the following error using this method: `Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Key, value: test-file.xlsx, type: <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

Comment: use the name of the field  you used in form for file.

Comment: Like `class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file_field = forms.FileField()` then `file_field` should be used in the parenthesis.